# share both y axis in subplots

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

i want to create a 3x2 grid of subplots with two y axis each. They should share all axis. x and y1 axis are shared by the option while creating subplots like this:

```
fig, axarray = plt.subplots(3,2, sharex = True, sharey = True)
z1 = 0
z2 = 0
ax = list()
counter = 0

for i in range(0,len(x)):

    axarray[z1,z2].plot( x[i] , y[i] )
    ax.append(axarray[z1,z2].twinx())

    if z2 == 0 :
        axarray[z1,z2].get_shared_y_axes().join(axarray[z1,z2], axarray[z1,z2+1])    <-<-<-<-
    ax[counter].plot( x[i] , y[i] , '-r' )

    counter += 1
    z2 += 1
    if z2 == 2:
        z1 += 1
        z2 = 0
```

basically the following line should share the y2 axis, like it is done with the other axis, between all subplots (found in an older thread), it's only updating the scale of the axis. z1 and z2 are defining the position of the plot.

```
axarray[z1,z2].get_shared_y_axes().join(axarray[z1,z2], axarray[z1,z2+1])
```

Is there any other way to share the y2 axis, since there is unfortunately no option for the subplot function?

[I get the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlGWu.png)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The line should read

```
axarray[z1,z2].get_shared_y_axes().join(axarray[z1,z2], ax[counter])
```

because you want to share `axarray[z1,z2]` with the newly created twinx axes and not some next axes.

[image]

Let me just say that sharing the y axis of a twinx is not actually useful, you can get the same effect by just activating the right ticklabels on the original axes.

Comment: I want to share the y axis of the twinx from all plots of the first column with them of the second. Therefore i tried to share it (z2==0 <-  the first column) with the plot with same z1, but z2=1.

Comment: The I do have problems understanding the whole issue. The plot created looks fine to me; what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The Subplots share the x and y1 axis. If the y2 axis are shared there won't be any label (i dont no the exactly word) between the plots, like it's the case between the plots in column 1. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Is this a problem of the labels or a problem of sharing axes? I even more lost on what the problem is. Maybe you clearly state which of the 12 axes should be shared with which other axes.

Comment: excuse me for my late answer. The y2 axis should be shared between all subplots like it is already done for the x and y2 axis (by 'sharex = True, sharey = True' in the subplots function). The labels are only an result.